# Weird behavior in Pyspark

Tags: python, date, pyspark, nonetype

I observed a weird behavior in PySpark. Maybe one of you will know what happens. If I do this:

```
def create_my_date(mydate):
       try:
           return mydate.strftime('%Y%m')
       except:
           return None

df = df.withColumn(
   "date_string", 
   F.udf(create_id, StringType())(df.mydate)
)

df.filter(~df.mydate.isNotNull()).count()
df.filter(df.mydate.isNotNull()).count()
```

This output:

```
0
10
```

It means I do not have Null value in the column df.mydate.

But If I change the create_my_date function and remove the try/except:

```
def create_my_date(mydate):
    return mydate.strftime('%Y%m')


df = df.withColumn(
    "date_string", 
    F.udf(create_id, StringType())(df.mydate)
)

df.filter(~df.mydate.isNotNull()).count()
df.filter(df.mydate.isNotNull()).count()
```

The JVM broke and say:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o7058.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 22 in stage 997.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 22.3 in stage 997.0 (TID 335940, 126.102.230.110, executor 29): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/home/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "/home/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 92, in <lambda>
    mapper = lambda a: udf(*a)
  File "/home/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "<ipython-input-109-422e4b5e07cf>", line 2, in create_my_date
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Do someone have an explanation for me ?

Thanks !

Comment: In `df.filter(~mydate.isNotNull()).count()` is `mydate` another dataframe? Or is it a typo? (I mean it should be `df.filter(~df.mydate.isNotNull()).count()` right?)

Comment: Thanks ! It was a typo.

Comment: Could you please run `df.select('mydate').show(20, False)` and post the results?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the attribute error is because you're trying to use strftime on a `None` type. You can see that the error is triggered during 'create_my_date', which since it's a udf is using the python representation of the rdd object. So essentially it's doing this:

```
>>> None.strftime("%Y%m")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Instead, you can accomplish what you want just using dataframe functions (faster than a udf, and doesn't need a try-except block):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
from datetime import datetime
df = spark.createDataFrame([[datetime(2018, 3, 2).date()], [None]], ["mydate"])

df = df.withColumn("date_string", date_format("mydate", "YMM"))
df.show()
```

The resulting dataframe:

```
    +----------+-----------+
    |    mydate|date_string|
    +----------+-----------+
    |2018-03-02|     201803|
    |      null|       null|
    +----------+-----------+
```

Then your count:

```
df.filter(df["mydate"].isNotNull()).count()
df.filter(df["mydate"].isNull()).count()
```

Returns as expected:

```
1
1
```